# Rounding a timedelta to the nearest 15 minutes

Tags: python, django

I have a timedelta which I would like to round to the nearest 15 minutes. For example, 8h 40m would round up to 8h 45m and 8h 50m would round down to 8h 45m.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up creating my own solution as I didn't find another way

```
def round_timedelta(td, period):
    """
    Rounds the given timedelta by the given timedelta period
    :param td: `timedelta` to round
    :param period: `timedelta` period to round by.
    """
    period_seconds = period.total_seconds()
    half_period_seconds = period_seconds / 2
    remainder = td.total_seconds() % period_seconds
    if remainder >= half_period_seconds:
        return timedelta(seconds=td.total_seconds() + (period_seconds - remainder))
    else:
        return timedelta(seconds=td.total_seconds() - remainder)
```

Used in iPython:

```
In [4]: print round_timedelta(timedelta(hours=1, minutes=27), timedelta(minutes=15))
1:30:00

In [5]: print round_timedelta(timedelta(hours=1, minutes=30), timedelta(minutes=15))
1:30:00

In [6]: print round_timedelta(timedelta(hours=1, minutes=31), timedelta(minutes=15))
1:30:00

In [7]: print round_timedelta(timedelta(hours=1, minutes=37), timedelta(minutes=15))
1:30:00

In [8]: print round_timedelta(timedelta(hours=1, minutes=38), timedelta(minutes=15))
1:45:00
```

Comment: did you check negative deltas?